# how to get user ID from wordpress and use it in another webpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a PHP file which creates new posts in the database of Wordpress
using this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_njvt_posts (post_date,post_date_gmt,post_author, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_content_filtered, guid, post_mime_type) VALUES (NOW(),NOW(),'1','$content1', '', '', '','$file','','','','http://www.sktcho.com/?p=$file','')";
```

Now I need to get the user ID from the Wordpress website and use it in this file to enable the user to create a new post from his account instead of user ID '1' which I am currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on what Dennis answered:

You can use the `wp_get_current_user()` on the wordpress site then build a function to pass the id to the other website, not really secure but could do it through a url variable for simplicity. Then just need to take the variable from the URL on the new site and create a cookie with the ID. I am in no way saying this is the best method or the proper way but would do what you need it to do, as long as all you need is the user id and don't need the active session.

Comment: I was thinking the same and wondering about this: How can he find out which user to take if there are multiple users logged in?

Comment: The wp_get_current_user() grabs it for each session, its not grabbing all users logged in to the site just whatever one hits the page that variable is on, I think my wording could be better on this. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem is to get the current user you need the session. If server a is accessing server b it has to pass that session. But since its on a different domaim it can't access the cookies and can't get the session. Am I wrong eith my thoughts?

Comment: Server A being the WordPress site would have a link setup directed towards the new site site2.com/index.php?ID=USERNAME using the php function I listed on site2.com it would take the URL variable create a new session/cookie so the other site knows what user it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) which returns the user which has the `ID` property. A look into the docs would help.

Comment: can you give an example if wp is installed in http://www.sktcho.com/  and the other php is under a different domain ?

Comment: I don't think thats possible. To get the current user you need the current session. But that is stored in a cookie which you can't access from a different domain. You could go through the wordpress database and look for all active sessions, but you can't find out which is the "right" one